# Convert video from webm to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, ffprobe

I have 10 webm videos, each one has the same size ~15mb. When I run following code:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.webm -f mp4 video1.mp4
```

9 of them finish in ~10 seconds, but 1 lasts more then 3 minutes. I run ffprobe to see difference and noticed only this:

```
25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
```

vs

```
1k tbr, 1k tbn (default)
```

Can someone please explain to me the difference and the best way to speed up the process to transform all 10 at nearly the same time?

Answer (score 1):

That anomalous file likely has been detected (wrongly) to have a high frame rate.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video1.webm -fps_mode passthrough -f mp4 video1.mp4
```

Your ffmpeg version should be recent i.e. at least `5.1`